# Setup RAID10 (mdadm and/or lvm) starting with three empty disks, then add fourth disk (has data in it)

Tags: lvm, raid, mdadm, software-raid

Please, tell me if it is possibile to create RAID10 (*near* layout) with odd drives and **then adding** even(th) disk to that existing RAID10.

- TOTAL: 4* 2TB drives (`sdc`,`sdd`,`sde`,`sdf`)
- FREE: 3 of them (`sdd`,`sde`,`sdf`) are empty / unpartitioned; ready to RAID
- IN-USE: **1 HDD (`sdc`) has data in it**

1. `mdadm` or `lvm` creation of RAID10 (*near* layout) using initially 3* 2TB HDDs (`sdd1`,`sde1`,`sdf1`)
2. format RAID10 with `ext4`
3. move all data from `sdc1` into the newly created RAID10 (`sdd1`+`sde1`+`sdf1`)
4. prepare `sdc` into `sdc1`
5. `mdadm` or `lvm` adding `sdc1` to the existing RAID10 (`sdd1`+`sde1`+`sdf1`)
6. mount RAID10 into `/somewhere/mystuff` via `/etc/fstab`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it this way. I'm not convinced that a layout of `sdd sde sdf missing` RAID10 gives you any more security than creating a RAID0 first (`sdd sde`) and converting (`sdd + sdf, sdc + sde`), but that's an academic discussion. You could do it either way.

`mdadm` uses the special keyword "missing" in place of a device name to create/manage degraded arrays. So when you create the array, you would run `mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=10 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1 /dev/sdf1 missing`. Once the data has copied over, you can simply add the remaining disk by running `mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sdc1`.

I highly recommend you create your array on top of partitions of type "Linux RAID" (`0xfd00` or `A19D880F-05FC-4D3B-A006-743F0F84911E`) rather than on the raw devices.

Comment: just for sake of "philosophy" dialog I'm curious ---> Why are you teling me about `sdd sde sdf missing` RAID1, even if asked infos bout RAID10? Also, are you telling me that with mdadm I could create a manual nested-RAID by first creating two RAID0 and then adding them manually to one RAID1? -- last "philosophic" question: will you go with RAID on devices `sdc sdd sde sdf`? Or with their partitions `sdc1 sdc2 sdd1 sdd2 sde1 sde2 sdf1 sdf2`?

Comment: @T.Caio 1) Sorry, that was a typo: `RAID1` should read `RAID10` (I've made the edit). 2) You could in theory create a nested RAID like you suggest., but I don't recommend it. 3) I **always** put RAID on partitions, never on raw devices. It makes it easier to move to smaller/larger devices in the future, and it really helps with auto-detection/auto-assembly/auto-mounting.

Comment: OK, as you pointed out in the original answer. Good! ;) Then'll be up to my decision if I want to create a single partition (eg: `totalsize-128MiB`) for each disk or to split them with multiple partitions... But that's another story.

Comment: @T.Caio You shouldn't add multiple partitions on the same device to a single array (or even multiple arrays). If you want to divide the space up further, I'd suggest using LVM.

Comment: Gothca. Well: I'll go with `mdadm`, good. ;)